# Дублирование подсказок visual studio code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

День добрый!
Проблема такая - в visual studio code дублируются подсказки кода, вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется, что вторую подсказку выдаёт плагин PHP Intelephense т.к. она более расширенная.
От куда берётся первая - понять не могу. Как можно отключить встроенную (первую) подсказку?

Answer (score 0):

За это отвечает параметр `php.suggest.basic`. В значении `false` - отключает встроенные подсказки